# Powerbi dates duplicates

Tags: sql, powerbi

I am trying to create relationship between two tables in Power BI between 2 tables, one with distinct date values and another tables. Its giving me an error

> cannot create relationship because one of the column needs to be unique.

The tables don't have any duplicates. I am stuck, please help

The dates are in the format "2020-05-19 20:26:32.4627518 -05:00" in the table
but when Power BI shows the date it shows as  "5/19/2020 20:26:01 PM".

Comment: We can't help you until you give us something to work with.

Comment: have a better look at your data and ensure that you have no duplicate keys, you can check it directly in PowerQuery. From the interface "GroupBy" -> operation: "Count Rows" (group by the key you are trying to use)

Comment: Thnanks for the replies, i have tried the count rows and it shows a few dates with duplicate values but in the table  i have checked each and every row but cannot find any duplicates, I also tried to do t he remove duplicates from powerbi itself but its not doing anything.

Comment: Remove duplicates works on the whole table, not on the single column, the duplicates are only in the column you are trying to use and probably are not removed due to values in other columns. Just go in your source data and check for the keys with more than one row. It might be useful to understand what you are trying to achieve (at a model level), maybe there are other solutions like using a calendar table

Comment: As i have only 347 rows in the column, i copied it over to excel and tried to remove duplicates and it did not do anything, moreover dates are in  below format so there is very little chance of duplicates.

The dates are in the format "2020-05-19 20:26:32.4627518 -05:00" in the table but when powerbi shows the date it shows as "5/19/2020 20:26:01 PM"

Comment: Not sure about what's the minimum precision offered by PowerBi when treating dates, but you can use datatype "Date/Time/Zone" which should be the most precise. In this case, I think the other table must share the same exact precision thought